# How to set up PDO connection in PHP with env variables that might change?

Tags: php, heroku, environment-variables

I have 2 sql servers. One is for locally, and one is for remote. To connect to my local server I have a .env.php file with my credentials and this is how my code look.

```
  include('./.env.php');
  $database = getenv('DB');
  $host = getenv('DB_HOST');
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", getenv('DB_USER'), getenv('DB_PASS'));
```

It all works fine as its supposed to. However, I have to also use Heroku and make an app there. I set my variables in Heroku to so it should connect to the remote server and access the other database, however when I open the app with heroku, I just get a http 500 error. I'm not sure what is going on and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _I just get a html 500 error._ I think you mean HTTP error code 500, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just edited it